# Detect Wii U button input in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, button, input, wii-u

I'm trying to get a website to detect a button input from the Wii U gamepad. When I press a button, nothing happens. [Here is some documentation](https://www.nintendo.com/wiiu/built-in-software/browser-specs/extended-functionality/) on the Wii U Browser. Also, [here](http://wiiubrew.org/wiki/Internet_Browser). Here is my code:

```
function reset() {
    var A = document.getElementById("A");
    A.style.color = "black";
}

if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("WiiU") != -1) { // = WiiU Browser
    var A = document.getElementById("A");

    // Register all values from GamePad.
    wiiu.gamepad.update();

    A.style.color = "black";

    if (wiiu.gamepad.hold == 0x00080000) // A
        A.style.color = "cyan";
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You wrote all that code before realising that it doesn't work? See [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok, I compressed the code. Thanks for the article.

Comment: Cleaned up formatting.

Comment: According to the docs, `A` is `0x00008000 ` while you have `0x00080000`. Looks like a typo then.